# grouby de células de um dataframe retorna Erro em eval (substitute (expr), envir, enclos): argumento não numérico para operador binário

Tags: r, group-by

Eu quero calcular as diferenças entre as células em um dataframe de uma coluna.

```
> head(df_benchmark)
        Date .STOXXR
1 2000-01-03  478.52
2 2000-01-04  459.53
3 2000-01-05  448.19
4 2000-01-06  446.24
5 2000-01-07  455.80
6 2000-01-10  462.97
```

O arquivo de dados é [aqui](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

Então eu tentei o seguinte:

```
df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df_benchmark[2] <- data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])

> library(lubridate)
> percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-gr) %>% 
+   as.matrix()
```

Ainda tenho um erro. Parece que meu dataframe com uma coluna de datas e uma coluna de valores deve ser um vetor atômico ou lista de 1d. Parece que a razão é um problema de variáveis:

```
Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: '.STOXXR'
```

## Outra tentativa

Eu usei `df_benchmark[2] <- data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])`. Isso foi usado porque eu tive um problema de formatação. Eu tentei sem. Então eu tentei o seguinte código:

```
library(xts)
df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)

percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
  ungroup()

# Generamos el xts, indicando la columna con la info de tiempo
monthly_return_benchmark <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr)
```

Mas eu tive o seguinte erro:

```
> library(xts)
> df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
> 
> percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup()
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

## Terceira tentativa

Somente usando o `group_by` usando os meses como unidades eu recebo o seguinte:

```
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+     group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month"))
> monthly_return_benchmark
Source: local data frame [4,604 x 3]
Groups: gr [216]

         Date .STOXXR         gr
       <date>   <chr>     <date>
1  2000-01-03  478.52 2000-01-01
2  2000-01-04  459.53 2000-01-01
3  2000-01-05  448.19 2000-01-01
4  2000-01-06  446.24 2000-01-01
5  2000-01-07   455.8 2000-01-01
6  2000-01-10  462.97 2000-01-01
7  2000-01-11  459.85 2000-01-01
8  2000-01-12  459.84 2000-01-01
9  2000-01-13  462.27 2000-01-01
10 2000-01-14  473.43 2000-01-01
# ... with 4,594 more rows
```

Agora eu tenho que fazer o `percent_change2` mas nunca funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso parece resolver o problema:

```r
txt <- "Data .STOXXR
2000-01-03  478.52
2000-01-04  459.53
2000-01-05  448.19
2000-01-06  446.24
2000-02-07  455.80
2000-02-10  462.97
"

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df_benchmark <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE, check.names = TRUE, 
                           colClasses = c("Date", "double")) %>% 
  as_tibble()


percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1

df_benchmark %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Data, unit = "month")) %>% 
  summarise(variacao = percent_change2(.STOXXR))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   gr         variacao
#>   <date>        <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01  -0.0675
#> 2 2000-02-01   0.0157
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As vezes para "debugar" um código com `pipe` (`%>%`) é bom ir rodando progressivamente cada parte que precede um `pipe`. Assim é fácil de ver o que está dando certo e onde está o erro.

Com o código que está acima, as linhas que sucedem o `summarise()` podem ser adicionadas sem problema:

```
df_benchmark %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Data, unit = "month")) %>% 
  summarise(variacao = percent_change2(.STOXXR)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr) %>% 
  as.matrix() 
#>         variacao
#> [1,] -0.06745800
#> [2,]  0.01573058
```